# Possible Absurdity while proving $1-\frac 12-\frac14+\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18+...$ converges to $\frac 12\log 2.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that the series $$1-\frac 12-\frac14+\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18+\frac 15-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12}+....$$ converges to $\frac 12\log 2.$

I tried solving the problem as follows:

The series given is, $1-\frac 12-\frac14+\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18+\frac 15-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12}+...$.

Let $$\sum u_n=1-\frac 12-\frac14+\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18+\frac 15-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12}+...,$$ where $\{u_n\}$ is a sequence defined by $$u_n=\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{4n-2}-\frac{1}{4n}.$$

We know that, $$\lim(1+\frac 12+...+\frac 1n-\log n)=\gamma.$$ Let $\gamma_n=1+\frac 12+...+\frac 1n-\log n\tag 1$ then, $\lim\gamma_n=\gamma.$

Let $t_n$ be the partial sum upto the $n-th$ term of of the given series. Then $$t_n=(1-\frac 12-\frac14)+(\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18)+(\frac 15-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12})+\cdots\text{ upto the nth term }.$$

We note, that $$t_{3n}=(1-\frac 12-\frac14)+(\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18)+(\frac 15-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12})+...+(\frac 1{6n-1}-\frac{1}{12n-2}-\frac{1}{12n}).$$

Now, $$t_{3n}=(1-\frac 12-\frac14)+(\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18)+(\frac 15-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12})+...+(\frac 1{6n-1}-\frac{1}{12n-2}-\frac{1}{12n})=(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\cdots +\frac{1}{12n})-2(\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots +\frac 1{12n}).$$

What we did, above is: We first wrote down all the $3n$ terms of the sum, and then subtracted all the even terms, twice, to again get back the *original sum.*

So, we have, $$t_{3n}=(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\cdots +\frac{1}{12n})-2(\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots +\frac 1{12n})=(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\cdots +\frac{1}{12n})-(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\cdots +\frac{1}{6n}).$$

Using $(1)$ we have, $$t_{3n}=\log {12n}+\gamma_{12n}-\log{6n}-\gamma_{6n}=\log 2+\gamma_{12n}-\gamma_{6n}.$$ Hence, $\lim t_{3n}=\log 2,$ immediately follows from this.

Also, $t_{3n+1}=t_{3n}+(\frac 1{6n+1}-\frac{1}{12n+2}-\frac{1}{12n+4})\implies \lim t_{3n+1}=\lim t_{3n}=\log 2.$

Similarly,$t_{3n+2}=t_{3n+1}+(\frac 1{6n+3}-\frac{1}{12n+6}-\frac{1}{12n+8})\implies \lim t_{3n+2}=\lim t_{3n+1}=\log 2.$

Hence, $\lim t_n=\log 2.$ Thus, the given series, to $\log 2.$

---

However, this does not match the claim, where it's given the point of convergence is $\frac{\log 2}{2}$ contrary to $\log 2.$ I couldn't find any mistake in my calculations. *To be precise, I am not interested in a solution of the above claim. I know that the claim holds good and there might be numerous ways of proving it.* Rather, I am interested in knowing what went wrong with my approach that it gave me a different result.

Comment: Much easier: Note, $1/(2n-1)-1/(4n-2)=1/(4n-2),$ so $$ u_n=\frac12\left(\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}\right),$$ So your sum is $$\frac12\left(\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots\right)$$ At least easier if you know that  inner series converges to $\ln2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews This seems strange, because, if you look at the the sequence $\{u_n\}$ then, each *term of the sequence* has $3$ distinct terms and the series is represented by $\sum u_n=u_1+u_2+u_3+...$ which seems to be in a good agreement with the series given explicitly. This seems paradoxical (?)

Comment: Can we use $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n}=C+\ln n +\varepsilon_n$, where $C$ is constant and $\varepsilon_n \to 0,n \to \infty$ ?

Comment: Which result are you speaking about?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the paradox, @ThomasFinley The terms initially come three at a time, one positive and two negative, but two of the three can be combined to give an equivalent sum of two terms. $u_n=v_{2n-1}-v_{2n},$ and $v_n\to 0,$ we know that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}v_k$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line, $$t_{3n}=(1-\frac 12-\frac14)+(\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18)+(\frac 15-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12})+...+(\frac 1{6n-1}-\frac{1}{12n-2}-\frac{1}{12n})\color{red}{=}(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\cdots +\frac{1}{12n})-2(\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots +\frac 1{12n}),$$ in OP, is incorrect.

The equality, marked with red is false. To be precise, the correct relation, is:

$$(1-\frac 12-\frac14)+(\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18)+(\frac 15-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12})+...+(\frac 1{6n-1}-\frac{1}{12n-2}-\frac{1}{12n})\color{green}{\neq}(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\cdots +\frac{1}{12n})-2(\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots +\frac 1{12n}).$$

This can be verified, simply, if, we take $n=1$ then, $t_3=u_1+u_2+u_3=(1-\frac 12-\frac 14)+(\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18)+(\frac 15-\frac 1{10}-\frac {1}{12}).$

On the other hand, $(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\cdots +\frac{1}{12n})-2(\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots +\frac 1{12n})=(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\cdots +\frac{1}{12})-2(\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots +\frac 1{12})=1-\frac 12+\frac 13-\frac 14+\frac 15-\frac 16+\color{red}{\frac 17}-\frac 18+\color{red}{\frac 19}-\frac 1{10}+\color{red}{\frac 1{11}}-\frac 1{12}.$

It can be observed, that the fractions marked in red, i.e $\{\frac 17,\frac 19,\frac 1{11}\}$ are not there, in the expression of $t_3.$ These terms, are thus "extra", and these "extra" terms result in the absurdity.

Answer (score 2):

**A Computation of the Sum**

By grouping the terms in threes (allowed because the terms tend to $0$), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{2k+1}-\frac1{4k+2}-\frac1{4k+4}\right)
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{4k+2}-\frac1{4k+4}\right)\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{2k+1}-\frac1{2k+2}\right)\tag{1b}\\
&=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}\tag{1c}\\[3pt]
&=\frac12\log(2)\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ combine the first two terms in each summand
$\text{(1b):}$ factor $\frac12$ out front
$\text{(1c):}$ write as an alternating sum
$\text{(1d):}$ use the power series for $\log(1+x)$

---

**Observations of the Question**

One has to be careful with non-absolutely convergent series about rearrangements. The step after the line "Now," does not look correct. You have
$$
\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{12n}\right)-2\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\cdots+\frac1{12n}\right)\tag2
$$
This is not the positive terms minus the negative terms. The positive terms are all odd.

Perhaps you are trying to include all the terms in the first parenthetical sum and then subtract the even terms (to get the odd terms), then get the given sum by multiplying the second parenthetical sum by $2$. However, this is not correct; the sum of the odd terms is
$$
\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{12n}\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\cdots+\frac1{12n}\right)\tag3
$$
Then, the even terms go twice as far as the odd terms; that is, the grouped terms are $\left(\frac1{2k+1}-\frac1{4k+2}-\frac1{4k+4}\right)$.  Thus, we should then subtract
$$
\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\cdots+\frac1{24n}\right)\tag4
$$
That is, the sum should be
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{12n}\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\cdots+\frac1{12n}\right)\right.\\
&\left.\phantom{\lim_{n\to\infty}}-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\cdots+\frac1{24n}\right)\right]\tag{5a}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{12n}\right)-\frac12\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{6n}\right)\right.\\
&\left.\phantom{{}=\lim_{n\to\infty}}-\frac12\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{12n}\right)\right]\tag{5b}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[(\log(12n)+\gamma_{12n})-\frac12(\log(6n)+\gamma_{6n})-\frac12(\log(12n)+\gamma_{12n})\right]\tag{5c}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac12\log(2)+\frac12(\gamma_{12n}-\gamma_{6n})\right]\tag{5d}\\
&=\frac12\log(2)\tag{5e}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(5b):}$ factor $\frac12$ out of the last two sums
$\text{(5c):}$ use the expressions for the Harmonic Numbers from the question
$\text{(5d):}$ cancel
$\text{(5e):}$ take the limit

Comment: From where are you getting the $\frac{1}{24n}$ term ?

Comment: That is the greatest of the even terms for the odd terms that are included in the expression above.

Comment: Well, the part where you say, "Perhaps you are trying to include all the terms in the first parenthetical sum and then subtract the even terms (to get the odd terms) by multiplying the second parenthetical sum by $2$." No, what I am doing is:"I am trying to include all the terms in the first parenthetical sum and then subtract the even terms  by multiplying the second parenthetical sum by $2$, to get the **original series**"

Comment: Does the difference of the two lines I give make sense to you? The first line is the odd terms, the second line is the even terms. Subtract the second line from the first and you should get the proper sum. If not, let me know and I will try to be clearer.

Comment: @ThomasFinley: I have expanded the second part of my answer. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: In case of pattern like - 'odd' terms followed by negative 'even' terms, there is a generalisation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4719949/266435). I think a similar generalisation should be possible in case negative 'even' terms are followed by odd terms.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here

$$t_{3n}=\left(1-\frac 12-\frac14\right)+\left(\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18\right)+\left(\frac 15-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12}\right)+\ldots+\left(\frac 1{6n-1}-\frac{1}{12n-2}-\frac{1}{12n}\right)
=\color{red}{\left(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\cdots +\frac{1}{12n}\right)-2\left(\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots +\frac 1{12n}\right)}=$$

$$= \color{red}{\frac{1}{6n+1}+\frac{1}{6n+2}+\ldots +\cdots +\frac{1}{12n}}$$

indeed

$$t_{3n}=\left(\color{magenta}1-\frac 12-\frac14\right)+\left(\color{magenta}{\frac 13}-\frac 16-\frac 18\right)+\left(\color{magenta}{\frac 15}-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12}\right)+\ldots+\left(\color{magenta}{\frac 1{6n-1}}-\frac{1}{12n-2}-\frac{1}{12n}\right)=\left(\color{magenta}{1+\frac 13+\frac 15+\cdots +\frac{1}{6n-1}}\right)-\left(\frac 12+\frac14+\ldots+\frac{1}{12n-2}+\frac{1}{12n}\right)$$

which looks totally different from the red line.

We can proceed for example as follows

$$t_{3n}=\left(1-\frac 12-\frac14\right)+\left(\frac 13-\frac 16-\frac 18\right)+\left(\frac 15-\frac {1}{10}-\frac {1}{12}\right)+\ldots+\left(\frac 1{6n-1}-\frac{1}{12n-2}-\frac{1}{12n}\right)
=\left(1+\frac 12 +\frac 13 +\cdots +\frac{1}{6n-1}\right)-\left(\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots +\frac 1{6n-2}\right)-\left(\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots +\frac 1{12n}\right)=$$

$$=H_{6n-1}-\frac12H_{3n-1}-\frac12H_{6n}=$$

$$= \frac12H_{6n}-\frac12H_{3n} +O\left(\frac1n\right)\to \frac12\log 2$$

Comment: Why did you write $\frac {1}{12n-1}$ at the 4th line, shouldn't it be, $\frac {1}{12n-2}$ ?

Comment: @ThomasFinley I'm collecting terms up to$ \frac1{2n-2}$ and $-\frac 1{12n-1}$ goes out.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand the mistake. I think the red part in your answer, needs a little elaboration if not an explanation.

Comment: Yes there is something to fix!

Comment: @ThomasFinley Now fixed, the mistake is in the red line, you have grouped the single terms wrongly. I've proposed a way but we can of course use others method.

Comment: But how do you claim, I grouped them wrongly, I verified them, but unfortunately I found nothing absurd! I feel the grouping might be correct...

Comment: @ThomasFinley For example, in the first line $t_{3n}$ has not a $1/12n$ term, but the red line has that term.

Comment: The positive terms are up to $1/(6n-1)$, not $1/12n$. There is something wron in that line.

Comment: @ThomasFinley I've added some more detail.

Comment: @ThomasFinley Note also that the term $1$ cancel out in the red line. I'm sure it is wrong, please revise the way you have grouped numbers here.

Comment: Wait, wait, just a second. The thing is, that I tried adding all the $3n$ terms of the series and I noticed, that the even terms, are negative, so I just subtracted them twice, to keep the series, intact. What's the problem there? You just arranged it differently.

Comment: @ThomasFinley We can arrange in different way but note that in the red line you are cancelling out $1$, $1/2$ up to the $1/6n$ terms. It isn't clear to me how you have derived this line but it is wrong.