# Problem when proving the series $1+\frac 13-\frac 12+\frac 15+\frac17-\frac 14 +\frac 19+\frac 1{11}-\frac 16+...$ converges to $\frac 32\log 2.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that the series $$1+\frac 13-\frac 12+\frac 15+\frac17-\frac 14 +\frac 19+\frac 1{11}-\frac 16+\cdots$$ converges to $\frac 32\log 2.$

I tried solving the problem as follows:

The series given is $$1+\frac 13-\frac 12+\frac 15+\frac17-\frac 14 +\frac 19+\frac 1{11}-\frac 16+\cdots.$$

We write the given series as $\sum u_n$ where $\{u_n\}$ is a sequence defined by $u_n=\frac{1}{4n-3}+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{2n},\forall n\in\Bbb N.$

We consider the partial sum of the given  series $t_n=u_1+u_2+u_3+...+u_n$( consisting of $n$ terms).

Then, $$t_{3n}=u_1+u_2+\cdots +u_{3n}=(1+\frac 13-\frac 12)+(\frac 15+\frac17-\frac 14) +(\frac 19+\frac 1{11}-\frac 16)+\cdots+(\frac{1}{12n-3}+\frac{1}{12n-1}-\frac{1}{6n})=(1+\frac 13+\frac 15+\frac 17+...+\frac{1}{12n-1})-(\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 16+\cdots +\frac 1{6n})\tag 1.$$

(Till now, we have grouped all the odd terms (positive terms) together and the negative terms( even terms) together *in the partial sum, above.*) Next, we add and subtract  $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+...+\frac{1}{12n}$ in the right hand side of the above equality $(1)$ and rearrange, to get the *partial sum $t_{3n}$ of the series* as,

$$t_{3n}=(1+\frac 13+\frac 15+\frac 17+...+\frac{1}{12n-1})-(\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 16+\cdots +\frac 1{6n})=(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\cdots +\frac{1}{12n-1})-(\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 16+\cdots +\frac {1}{12n})-(\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 16+\cdots +\frac 1{6n})=(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\cdots +\frac{1}{12n-1})-2(\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac 16+\cdots +\frac {1}{6n})-(\frac1{6n+2}+\frac{1}{6n+4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{12n})=(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\cdots +\frac{1}{12n-1})-( 1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\cdots +\frac {1}{3n})-(\frac1{6n+2}+\frac{1}{6n+4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{12n})\tag 2$$

We know that, $\lim(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\cdots+ \frac 1n-\log n)=\gamma.$ Let, $1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\cdots+ \frac 1n-\log n=\gamma_n\tag 3$ then, $\lim\gamma_n=\gamma.$

Using $(3),$ the  equality $(2)$ can be written as, $$t_{3n}=(1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\cdots +\frac{1}{12n-1})-( 1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\cdots +\frac {1}{3n})-(\frac1{6n+2}+\frac{1}{6n+4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{12n})=\log(12n-1)+\gamma_{12n-1}-\log(3n)-\gamma_{3n}-S,$$
where $S=\frac1{6n+2}+\frac{1}{6n+4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{12n}.$

We also, note that, $\lim S=0.$

We now proceed to evaluate the limit of $t_{3n}=\log(12n-1)+\gamma_{12n-1}-\log(3n)-\gamma_{3n}-S=\log(4-\frac{1}{3n})+\gamma_{12n-1}-\gamma_{3n}+S.$ We observe,

$$\lim t_{3n}=\log 4=2\log 2.$$

As, $t_{3n+1}=t_{3n}+u_{3n+1}$ and $t_{3n+2}=t_{3n+1}+u_{3n+2},$ we have, $$\lim t_{3n+1}=\lim t_{3n+2}=\lim t_{3n}=2\log 2.$$

So, $\lim t_n=2\log 2.$ Hence, the series $$1+\frac 13-\frac 12+\frac 15+\frac17-\frac 14 +\frac 19+\frac 1{11}-\frac 16+\cdots$$ converges to $2\log 2.$

---

However, as it turns out, this gives the value $2\log 2$ contrary to what was required to be established, i.e $\frac 32\log 2.$ The problem, is precisely, I find no mistake in my solution. I want to know where did things go wrong. Specifically, where is the mistake in this solution?

### A New Issue

As pointed out, in the comment, by @metamorphy, it seems that the evaluation of the limit .i.e $\lim S=0$ is incorrect. It should be, as follows:

> $$S=\frac1{6n+2}+\frac{1}{6n+4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{12n}\implies 2S=\frac1{3n+1}+\frac1{3n+2}+\dots+\frac1{6n}\\=\left(1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1{6n}\right)-\left(1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1{3n}\right)\\=\big(\gamma_{6n}+\log(6n)\big)-\big(\gamma_{3n}+\log(3n)\big).$$ This means, $\lim 2S=\log 2,$ or $\lim S=\frac 12 \log 2.$

But here's the problem, what went wrong with this reasoning, i.e the reason by which, I concluded $\lim S$ is $0$ which is:

> $$S=\frac1{6n+2}+\frac{1}{6n+4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{12n},$$ so, limit of each of the terms $\lim\frac{1}{6n+r}=0$, such that $r\in\{2,4,...,6n\}.$  This, means $\lim S=0.$

I want to know the mistake in this second limit evaluation explicitly ?

Comment: Your "$\lim S=0$" is *exactly* the mistake.

Comment: @metamorphy Why?

Comment: The third term in your five-times-written-out series is wrong.

Comment: @JohnBentin It will be helpful, if you specifically mention which term. It looks confusing. Are you talking about the term $-\frac 12$ ?

Comment: *Why?* - because, in your terms, $2S_{\color{red}{n}}=\big(\gamma_{6n}+\log(6n)\big)-\big(\gamma_{3n}-\log(3n)\big)\to\log 2$.

Comment: @metamorphy I still don't understand, I mean, I have never used the term $S_{\color{red}{n}}$ ? How do you even obtain that relation with $2S_{\color{red}{n}}=...$?

Comment: Chewed a bit more: you have written $$S=\frac1{6n+2}+\frac1{6n+4}+\dots+\frac1{12n},$$ and this has to be denoted like $S_{\color{red}{n}}$ since the RHS depends on $n$. Now $$2S_n=\frac1{3n+1}+\frac1{3n+2}+\dots+\frac1{6n}\\=\left(1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1{6n}\right)-\left(1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1{3n}\right)\\=\big(\gamma_{6n}+\log(6n)\big)-\big(\gamma_{3n}+\log(3n)\big).$$

Comment: @metamorphy Thanks a lot! I  understand. If you consider posting your comment as an answer, I 'll be glad to accept it! But just one more: there was admittedly a temptation, to write, $\lim S=0$ so, how to overcome this deception. I mean, what to look out for to avoid this type of mistake ?

Comment: Metamorphy has corrected it for you.

Comment: @JohnBentin Yeah, thanks to him!

Comment: Just to let people know, OP asked a related question yesterday. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4719437/possible-absurdity-while-proving-1-frac-12-frac14-frac-13-frac-16-frac-18

Comment: @AdamRubinson Umm...I am not sure what you are trying to imply. Did I do something wrong? The questions are from the same topic, "Sequences and Series", but if you take a look at them, then it seems, that the issues are totally different. Here, the evaluation of limit wasn't correct, there, the formula pushing was invalid. So, I don't know what you want.

Comment: I'm just observing; I'm not implying anything. Your questions seem fine and in the spirit of the site. I also think what you're doing by putting further questions into the body of this question to avoid make new questions is a good idea.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Ah, that makes things clearer. Thanks! Btw, Your suggested answer in the other post, is good to go! Thanks for that also!

Comment: There is no issue. You do $\lim_n (x_n+y_n)= \lim x_n +\lim y_n$ when there are finitely many (fixed) summands. Clearly, $1= 1/n +1/n +1/n+...+1/n$ (n -terms) but $\lim (1/n+1/n+...+1/n)\ne \color{red}{\lim 1/n +\lim 1/n+...+\lim 1/n)= 0}$

Comment: @Koro If you add this comment to your answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: (incorporated this comment into my answer to get this question off the unanswered queue.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no issue. You do $\lim_n (x_n+y_n)= \lim x_n +\lim y_n$ when there are finitely many (fixed) summands. Clearly, $1= 1/n +1/n +1/n+...+1/n$ but $\lim (1/n+1/n+...+1/n)\ne \color{red}{\lim 1/n +\lim 1/n+...+\lim 1/n= 0}$. So you made an error in computing $\lim S$.

---

Here is a generalisation: taking $a$ 'odd' terms followed by $b$ 'even' negative terms.

Specifically, consider the series $$1+1/3+...+\frac 1{2a-1}-\color{blue}{1/2-1/4-...-\frac 1{2b}}+\frac 1{2a+1}+...+\frac 1{4a-1}-\color{blue}{\frac 1{2b+2}-...-\frac 1{4b}}+...$$ $\tag A$

**Result $1$:** The above series has sum $=\log \left(2\sqrt \frac ab\right)$.

**Pf:**
Consider the $(a+b)n$-th partial sum

$$S_{(a+b)n}=1+1/3+...+\frac 1{2a-1}-\left(1/2+1/4+...+\frac 1{2b}\right)+\cdots+\frac 1{2(n-1)a+1}+\cdots\\+\frac 1{2na-1}-\left(\frac 1{2b(n-1)+2}+\cdots+\frac 1{2nb}\right)$$

$S_{(a+b)n}= H_{2na}- \left(\frac 12+\frac 14+\cdots+\frac 1{2na}\right)-\frac 12 H_{nb}= H_{2na}-\frac 12 H_{na}-\frac 12 H_{nb}$

$S_{(a+b)n}= \log 2na - \frac{\log na +\log nb}{2}+o(1)\to \log\left(2\sqrt{\frac ab}\right)$ as $n\to \infty$.

(**B**) It can be shown that for every $m\in \{1,2,...,a+b-1\}, S_{(a+b)n+m}\to \log \left(2\sqrt \frac ab\right)$.

It follows that the series has sum $=\log \left(2\sqrt \frac ab\right). \square$

---

To compute the sum of the series in your post: put $a=2, b=1$.

---

(**B**) To see why it answers the question, note the following result:

**Result 2:** Let $\{m_l\}, \{n_k\}$ be *exhausting, disjoint* subsets of $\mathbb N$ (by exhausting it is meant that the union of the indices is $\mathbb N$) such that $m_l<m_{l+1}, n_k<n_{k+1}$ for every $l,k\in \mathbb N$. Then the sequence $(x_n), x_n\in \mathbb R$ converges iff the subsequences $(x_{m_l}), (x_{n_k})$ converge to the same limit. (Let's call such subsequences 'complementary subsequences')

Let's see how this result alongwith (**B**) completes the proof of **Result $1$**. Suppose Result $2$ is true, then we can extend it any finite collection of complementary subsequences. Let's use this on the sequence of partial sums $(S_n)$ of the series in $(A)$. The subsequences $(S_{(a+b)n+m})$ in (**B**) are complementary and have the same sum viz. $\log \left(\sqrt{\frac ab} \right)$ so we are done.

**Pf. of Result $2$:** $(\Rightarrow)$ Every subsequence of a convergent sequence converges to the same limit so this part is proved.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose on the contrary that the sequence $(x_p)$ doesn't converge. Suppose the complementary subsequences converge to $L$. It follows that there exists some $\epsilon_0$ and a subsequence $(x_{p_t})_{t=1}^\infty$ such that $|x_{p_t}-L|\ge \epsilon_0$ for all $t\in \mathbb N$.

By the convergence of complementary subsequences, there exists $N\in \mathbb N$ such that for all $m_l, n_k\gt N$, $|x_{m_l}-L|<\epsilon_0, |x_{n_k}-L|<\epsilon_0$. Since the indices $\{m_l\}, \{n_k\}$ are exhausting, assume wlog that there exists some $m_k\gt N$ such that $x_{m_k}= x_{p_T}$ for some $T$, so we must have $|x_{p_T}-L|=|x_{m_k}-L|<\epsilon_0$, which is a contradiction.

This proves **Result $2$**.

Comment: @ThomasFinley: See my comment down your post. This answers your question and gives a generalisation also, thus answering your latest post as well :-)

Comment: One still needs to justify that if by introducing  parentheses to a series $\sum_na_n$  convergence to a number $s$  occurs, then the original series converges and that the summation is also $s$. To be more precise, if for some monotone increasing function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, one defines $b_1=a_1+\ldots + a_{p(1)}$, and $b_n=a_{p(n)+1}+\ldots + a_{p(n+1)}$ for $n\geq2$, under some conditions, $\sum_na_n$ converges iff $\sum_nb_n$ converges and in such a case, $\sum_na_n=\sum_nb_n$.

Comment: 1) the purpose of parentheses in the original series was to show pattern of the terms in the series but it wasn't mentioned and is not even a common practice so I removed them and colorcoded (in blue) the terms instead. 2) Rearrangement here is not an issue:  a) Lemma: if $\{n_l\}$ and $\{m_k\}$ are exhausting disjoint indices (i.e. $n_l < n_{l+1}, m_k< m_{k+1}, \mathbb N= \cup_l\cup_k \{n_l\}\cup \{m_k\} $, then the sequence $(x_n)$ converges iff the subsequences $(x_{n_l}), (x_{m_k})$ converge to the same limit.

Comment: @Mittens (Contd.)  b) note that the indices in 
 $S_{(a+b)n+m}, m= 1,2,...,a+b-1$ are disjoint, exhaust $\mathbb N$ and for every $m$, $S_{(a+b)n+m}$  converges to $\log \left(2\sqrt{\frac ab}\right)$so by the lemma in a), the sequence of partial sums $(S_n)$ converges hence we are done.

Comment: @Mittens: I have added the details in the post.

Comment: The rick is not the the indices exhausts $\mathbb{N}$ but that the increments of the indices have finite range and the main term of the series goes to $0$.  Once the  bracketed series is shown to converge, the original series doe so with the same limit and then, no matter how the series is rebracketed, convergence is preserved to the same limit.

Comment: @Mittens: there are no brackets here. I don't see what you objection is here.

Comment: The brackets are the terms that are added from passing to $s_{n_k} $ to $s_{n_{k+1}}$. Anyway, it is a trivial problem and just want to point out why the trucks used here work.

Comment: @Mittens: To take care of that, I've written out a lemma to explain those details :).

Comment: Just be careful with adding and/or undoing baskets ( I call them parenthesis). For exmample $\sum_n(-1)^n$ diverges, but if you add brackets of even length one gets a convergent series, ig one adds brackets of odd range we also get a convergent sequence. The problem here is that the main term of the series $(-1)^n$ does not converge to $0$. That is why one should look that the main term of the original series converges to $0$, then parenthesis may produce something simpler which will allow one to estimate the convergence of the original series. That is all I wanted to point out.

Comment: @Mittens: yes, Result 2 in the post takes care of parentheses. In case of $\sum (-1)^n, s_{2n}=0, s_{2n+1}=-1$ so the Result 2 is not satisfied hence $\lim s_n=:\sum_n (-1)^n$ doesn't exist. That's one way. Another way is to see that the series doesn't satisfy the necessary condition of convergent of series which is nth term should have limit 0 as n tends to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem on introducing parenthesis on a series. This technique is very common and is justified by the following result:

> **Lemma I:** Suppose $p:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ is a strictly monotone increasing function. Let series $\sum_na_n$ and $\sum_nb_n$ be series related as follows
> \begin{align}
> b_1&=a_1+\ldots+a_{p(1)}\\
> b_n&=a_{p(n)+1}+\ldots a_{p(n+1)}, \qquad n\geq2
> \end{align}
> If $M:=\sup_n(p(n+1)-p(n))<\infty$ and $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$, the series $\sum_na_n$ converges iff the series $\sum_nb_n$ converges. In such case, the sum is the same.

The series in the OP
$$\sum_na(n)=1+\frac13-\frac12+\frac15+\frac17-\frac14+\ldots$$
has its $n$-th term defined as
\begin{align}
a(3n)&=-\frac{1}{2n}\\
a(3n-1)&=\frac{1}{2(2n)-1}\\
a(3n-2)&=\frac{1}{2(2n-1)-1}
\end{align}
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Define $p(n)=3n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and consider adding parenthesis of length 3 to the series $\sum_na_n$, that is
\begin{align}
b_1&=a(1)+a(2)+a(3)=1+\frac13-\frac12\\
b_n&=a(3n+1)+a(3n+2)+a(3n+3)=\frac{1}{4n+1}+\frac{1}{4n+3} -\frac{1}{2(n+1)}
\end{align}

Clearly $a(n)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. On the other hand,
$t_n:=\sum^n_{n=1}b_n$ can be expressed as
$$t_n=\sum^{2n+1}_{k=1}\frac{1}{2k+1}-\frac12\sum^{n+1}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$$

Now we exploit the scaling properties of the harmonic series $\sum_n\frac1n$. Let $H_n:=\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k}$. It is well known that
$$H_n=\log n+\gamma +O(\frac1n)$$
where $\gamma$ is some constant. Then
\begin{align}
t_n&=H_{4n+3}-\frac12H_{2n+1}-\frac12 H_{n+1}\\
&=H_{4n+3}-H_{n+1} -\frac12(H_{2n+1}-H_{n+1})\\
&=\log\big(\frac{4n+3}{n+1}\big)-\frac12\log\big(\frac{2n+1}{n+1}\big)+O\big(\frac1n\big)
\end{align}
Passing to the limit, we obtain that
$$t_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\log 4-\frac12\log 2=\frac32\log2$$
By the  Lemma above, we obtain that
$$\sum_na_n=\sum_nb_n=\frac32\log2$$

No that the convergence if the series $\sum_na_n$ has been established, it is also true that any other system of parenthesis (with bounded or unbounded length) would produce the same result:

> **Lemma II:** Is a series $\sum_na_n$ converges to $s$, then every series $\sum_nb_n$ obtained from $\sum_na_n$ by inserting parentheses converges to $s$.

---

The Lemmas  above are not difficult to prove, they are discussed in many Calculus and Analysis textbooks. See for example Apostol, T., *Mathematical Analysis*, 2nd Edition, Addison-Wesley, 1974,  pp. 187.

Answer (score 2):

**Concerning the Question**

One small problem (which washes out since $\frac1{12n}\to0$) is that, in $(2)$, there is
$$
\scriptsize\left[\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{12n-1}\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\cdots+\color{#C00}{\frac1{12n}}\right)\right]-\left(\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac16+\cdots+\frac1{6n}\right)
$$
The bracketed piece is supposed to be the sum of the reciprocals of the odd numbers up to $12n-1$. However, there is a $-\frac1{12n}$ that is not cancelled. What should be there is
$$
\scriptsize\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\color{#C00}{\frac1{12n}}\right)-\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac16+\cdots+\color{#C00}{\frac1{12n}}\right)-\left(\frac 12+\frac 14+\frac16+\cdots+\frac1{6n}\right)
$$
So that the $-\frac1{12n}$ is cancelled.

At this point, the sum is
$$
\begin{align}
&(\log(12n)+\gamma)-\frac12(\log(6n)+\gamma)-\frac12(\log(3n)+\gamma)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\\
&=\frac32\log(2)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{align}
$$
which leads to the proper sum (as I said earlier, this washes out). In fact, the rest of $(2)$ is okay. Therefore, any problem must lie further on.

**The New Issue**

The mistake is saying that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{6n+2}+\frac1{6n+4}+\cdots+\frac1{12n}\right)=0
$$
This is actually
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac12\left(\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{6n}\right)-\left(1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1{3n}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac12((\log(6n)+\gamma)-(\log(3n)+\gamma))+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\\
&=\frac12\log(2)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{align}
$$
and there is the extra $\frac12\log(2)$.

For a **fixed** $k$, if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, then
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n+a_{n+1}+a_{n+2}+\dots+a_{n+k})=0
$$
In the case at hand, $k$ varies with $n$.

---

**A Similar Approach**

We will use the approximation
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k=\log(n)+\gamma+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag1
$$
We will group the terms into groups of three as in the question, which is okay since the terms tend to $0$.
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{4k-3}+\frac1{4k-1}-\frac1{2k}\right)
&=\overbrace{\color{#C00}{\sum_{k=1}^{4n}\frac1k}-\color{#090}{\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac1{2k}}}^{\text{odd terms to $4n-1$}}-\overbrace{\ \color{#B80}{\sum_{k=1}^{\vphantom{4}n}\frac1{2k}}\ }^{\substack{\text{even terms}\\\text{to $2n$}}}\tag{2a}\\
&=\color{#C00}{(\log(4n)+\gamma)}-\color{#090}{\frac12(\log(2n)+\gamma)}\\
&-\color{#B80}{\frac12(\log(n)+\gamma)}+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{2b}\\
&=\log(4)-\frac12\log(2)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac32\log(2)+O\!\left(\frac1n\right)\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ regroup the terms (allowed because the sum is finite)
$\text{(2b):}$ apply $(1)$, grouping the error terms
$\text{(2c):}$ collect and cancel
$\text{(2d):}$ simplify using $\log(4)=2\log(2)$

Taking the limit of $(2)$ as $n\to\infty$ gives
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{4k-3}+\frac1{4k-1}-\frac1{2k}\right)
=\frac32\log(2)\tag3
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us define two sequences:

$$
a_n:=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n},\qquad b_n:=\begin{cases}0 &\text{if $n\equiv 1\pmod 2$,}\\[10pt]\dfrac{(-1)^{n/2+1}}{n}&\text{if $n\equiv 0\pmod 2$.}\end{cases}
$$

Then
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n&=1-\frac 12+\frac 13-\frac 14+\frac 15-\frac 16+\frac 17-\frac 18+\ldots=\log 2\\[10pt]
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n&=0+\frac 12+0-\frac 14+0+\frac 16+0-\frac 18+\ldots=\frac 12\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=\frac 12\log 2\\
\end{align*}

Adding these squences we get
$$
a_n+b_n=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac 1n &\text{if $n\equiv 1\pmod 4$,}\\[10pt]
0 &\text{if $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$,}\\[10pt]
\dfrac 1n &\text{if $n\equiv 3\pmod 4$,}\\[10pt]
-\dfrac 2n &\text{if $n\equiv 0\pmod 4$.}
\end{cases}
$$

The corresponding series is the series which is discussed.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n+b_n)=1+0+\frac 13-\frac 12+\frac 15+0+\frac 17-\frac 14+\frac 19+0+\frac 1{11}-\frac 16+\ldots=\frac 32\log 2.
$$